# What is the alternative syntax for TO_CHAR() in Presto SQL?

Tags: presto

I came across this interesting date conversion table for postgresql and am wondering if this syntax for date patterns can also be used in presto. It might or might not work, anyone familiar with this?

[image]

Comment: Did you check [`date_format` Presto function](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_format)?

Comment: Hi yes, just wondering if to_char() works for presto!

Comment: There isn't. Added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent functionality is available through the [`date_format()` Trino (formerly Presto) function](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_format)

The `to_char` function does not exist in Presto.
Documentation contains the [list of builtin Presto functions](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions.html). When in doubt, you can get a list of all the functions available using the [`SHOW FUNCTIONS`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/show-functions.html) statement.